# passing textinput value from one screen into another using mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to pass value of a textinput from one screen to another using mapDispatchToProps. I am roughly a newbie in the redux world and I am a bit confused. kindly make corrections to my code below. I have tried using the example implemented on the documentation, however, I do not fully understand mapDispatchToProps.
PS I tried to keep the code as simple as possible for better understanding

Screen1

```
      import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
      import {
        View,
        Text,
        StyleSheet,
      } from 'react-native';
      import { connect } from 'react-redux';

      class Screen1 extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
          header: null,
        }

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            total: 1,
          };
          this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);

        }

        onChangeText(number) {
          const total = parseInt(number);
          if (number.length === 0) {
            this.setState({ total: '' });
          } else {
          this.setState({ total });
          }
        }


        render() {
          return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                  <ScrollView
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollableList}
                  >

                    <InputField
                      children={"Receiver's phone no."}
                      iconType={'ios-call'}
                      placeholder={"number"}
                      keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                      maxLength={11}
                    />
                    <InputField
                      children={"Receiver's gifts"}
                      iconType={'ios-basket'}
                      placeholder={'Gifts'}
                      keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                      maxLength={2}
                      onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                      value={this.state.total.toString()}
                    />

                  </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          );
        }
      }

      function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
          total: () => {
            dispatch(this.onChangeText());
          }
        }
      }

      export default connect(mapDispatchToProps) (Screen1);
```

Screen2

```
      import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
      import {
        View,
        Text,
        StyleSheet,
      } from 'react-native';
      import { connect } from 'react-redux';

      class Screen2 extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
          header: null,
        }

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
          };
        }


        render() {
          return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.AndroidSafeArea}>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                  <ScrollView
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollableList}
                  >
                  <Text>{this.props.onChangeText}</Text>
                  </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          );
        }
      }

      function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
          total: state.onChangeText
          }
        }
      }

      export default connect(mapStateToProps) (Screen2);
```

Reducer.js

```
      import { TOTAL_GIFTS } from '../actions/types';

      const initialState = {
        total: ''
      };

      const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case TOTAL_GIFTS:
            return {
              ...state,
              total: action.total
            };

          default:
            return state;

        }
      };

      export default Reducer;
```

Comment: first change this : ```export default connect(mapDispatchToProps) (Screen1);```  to ```export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(screen)``` connect expects first argument to be mapping state to prop function.

Comment: okay, do you think that is the only problem?

Comment: you didn't mention what was the problem? is there an error or something else?

Comment: was not getting any error precisely, just was not getting the textinput value
I want to get the text input value in another screen onchangetext because I do not have any submit button

Answer (score 0):

Im leaving the none redux related parts of your code out.

Screen1

```js
class Screen1 extends React.component{
    handleChange(number){
        this.props.announceChange(number)
    }
}
//mapping dispatch to props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    announceChange(number)
}
//action creator
function announceChange(number){
    return {type:'SOME_CONSTANT',payload:number}
}
export default connect(null,mapStateToProps)(Screen1)
```

Reducer:

```js
export default function reducer(state={},action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SOME_CONSTANT':
            return {...state,number:action.payload}
        default :
            return state;
    }
}
```

screen2:

```js
class Screen2 extends React.component{
    render(){
        const {number} = this.props
        return(
            <span>{number}</span>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        number : state.reducername
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen2);
```

the above code is a minimal sample of the way you can use redux. if you dont have any ideas how to setup your store,reducer and other redux stuff reading [this](https://blog.tylerbuchea.com/super-simple-react-redux-application-example/) wont take more than 10 mints.

Answer (score 0):

**mapDispatchToProps**: are functions/actions to update store(redux)

**mapStateToProps**  : to get data from store(redux)

**on first screen you will disptach action to update email using mapDispatchToProps**

**on second you will get email from mapStateToProps**

I have created a sample code for you **(CHECK IN ANDROI/IOS)**
Please check https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/reduxtest

**APP PREVIEW**

[image]

Comment: As i said in answer PLEASE(CHECK IN ANDROI/IOS). Right side you have 3 options change option . Web version have issue default to redux . it is not code issue . please check it